# Making Start Command Work in batch File

Tags: batch-file

I have the following, but when I execute, I find the FOR loop never seems to run - which is interesting is that Start statements after the for loop will execute. I'm a little perplexed.

```
Start "Starting up Master Node" /D "c:\mydir" cmd /k "Master.exe"
FOR /L %%i in (1,1,%SlaveNodes%) DO (call slavenode.bat  %%i %mycores%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your batch flow:

```
Start "Starting up Master Node" /D "c:\mydir" cmd /k "Master.exe"
```

This command will start another process (other them initial one) to run `cmd /K Master.exe`.

So, in this new process, `Master.exe` is executed and `/K` window remain open.

At same time, original process continues to

```
FOR /L %%i in (1,1,%SlaveNodes%) DO (call slavenode.bat  %%i %mycores%)
```

Executing `slavenode.bat` `%SlaveNodes%` times (in original process).

Then, terminates. If original process is started from a non persistent method (eg, from Explorer) original process window (if any) disappears.

If you were expecting `Master.exe` to see something from `slavenode.bat`, keep in mind that as it is started in a new process, this overhead before execution can take longer then all slaves to run.

Comment: OK. I need to run the Initial Start Command in parallel with the Loop command. So if I go around the loop 4 times, I would expect 5 windows open because I have a Start Command in the slavenode.bat file. However this doesn't seem to happen. MasterNode will never return and runs indefinitely. However I never see the FOR loop executed.

Comment: Is `%SlaveNodes%==5`? Is your file named `cmd` or any other conflicting command name?